# SwiftUI - Form "styling" being applied to navigation destination view

Tags: swiftui, ios13

In SwiftUI, whenever a NavigationLink is inside a form, the destination view also seems to "styled" as if it's also in the form. This makes sense for pickers and such, but I'm just wanting to display a list of messages for an internal app that includes a simple email client. See recreated example below.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct BasicRootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                MailboxListView()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FormRootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                MailboxListView()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct MessageListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<30) { i in
            Text("Message \(i)")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Mailbox", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct MailboxListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("account@domain.com").font(.headline)) {
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageListView()) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "tray")
                        .font(.body)
                    Text("Inbox")
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageListView()) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                        .font(.body)
                    Text("Sent")
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageListView()) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "bin.xmark")
                        .font(.body)
                    Text("Spam")
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: MessageListView()) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                        .font(.body)
                    Text("Trash")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Accounts")
    }
}
```

The BasicRootView above doesn't look as I want it to, but the destination of its links looks like a normal list. So when I try to put it in a form to get the layout and look I'm going for, the destination list now itself looks like it's in a form as well, an unnecessary gap between the start of the list and the nav bar.

[image: BadFolderView]

^^ No good

[image: GoodMessageView]

^^ Good

[image: GoodFolderView]

^^ Good

[image: BadMessageView]

^^ No Good

Any way to "shed" the form in a destination view?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, Xcode 11 Beta 7, iOS 13 Beta 8 (NOT 13.1 Beta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the listStyle for both of your lists:

```
struct FormRootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                MailboxListView()
            }   .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}


struct MessageListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<30) { i in
            Text("Message \(i)")
            }   .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("Mailbox", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can confirm adding this to the Destination also works:  `NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView().listStyle(PlainListStyle())) { NavigationLinkView() }`